# Linq expression to call Contains method with nullable parameter

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-expressions

I have database column

```
SelectListId int null
```

And I have complicated filter on web page, which I am trying to transfer to `LinqToSql` in order to get filtered data from database.

I have several expressions which works, but one I struggle with.

I would like to call something like this `x => SelectedIdsByUser.Contains(x.SelectListId)`

So I have a function which returns predicate

```
// this function works for 'SelectListId int not null' columns
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> SelectListContainsPredicate<T>(string columnName, List<int> searchValues)
{
      var type = typeof(T);
      ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
      ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(true);

      // When column is invalid, return true
      PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == columnName);

      if (property == null || searchValues.Count == 0)
      {
          return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(constant, parameter);
      }

      // Define expression :
      // x => SearchValues.Contains(x.Column)

      MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(parameter, property);

      MethodInfo method = typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Contains");

      constant = Expression.Constant(searchValues);

      // Here it throws :
      // System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' 
      // cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Int32' of method 'Boolean Contains(Int32)'
      // Because: column is int? and List<int>.Contains(int?) doesn't work.
      Expression expression = Expression.Call(constant, method, member);

      return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, parameter);
}
```

but I am getting an error, because `SelectListId` is `Nullable<int>` but `Contains` method has only `int` parameter. What can I do here, any Idea ?

> System.ArgumentException: Expression of type
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'  cannot be used for parameter of
>   type 'System.Int32' of method 'Boolean Contains(Int32)'

Answer (score 1):

use

```cs
x => ( x.SelectListId != null ) ? SelectedIdsByUser.Contains( (int)(x.SelectListId) ) : 0
```

and replace 0 by intendent value.

Comment: Hi draz, how can I do `(int)(x.SelectListId)` in Expression.Call ?

Comment: i fixed it to `(int)(x.SelectListId)`

Comment: youre looking for `mycollection.Where( x => (x.SelectListId != null) ? SelectedIdsByUser.Contains((int)(x.SelectListId)) : false );`?

Comment: even better: `mycollection.Where(x => (x.SelectListId != null) && SelectedIdsByUser.Contains((int)(x.SelectListId)) );`

Answer (score 1):

I found solution here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.convert?view=netframework-4.8

there is `Expression.Convert` method, I used :-)

```
Expression memberAsInt = Expression.Convert(member, typeof(Int32));

Expression expression = Expression.Call(constant, method, memberAsInt);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, parameter);
```